# tightly fitting TikZ image, robust way

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose one would like to draw a pair of ellipses, as these:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (c0) at (5cm,5cm);
        \tikz \draw (c0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
        \coordinate (c1) at ($(c0)+(5cm,0cm)$);
        \tikz \draw (c1) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The actual image does not matter. Somehow, in previous drawings, I used to have
some dimensions and by some trial-error I managed to have a decent (vector) image.
Now, it is time to ask this question about the most robust way to do so.
So, the above image produces essentially nothing. By playing with dimensions
I can get more-less acceptable image. However, I would like to know how exactly
to set dimensions (`ex,em,cm,pt` or something else) and the sizes so that
I get a TikZ image, centered, and tightly fitting a page? What is the most "robust"
and "cross-platform" way?
I presumed the `standalone` was for that.
I mean, using a WYSIWYG image editor you can get a basic image such as two ellipses inside a rectangle, all centered in a page by just drag and drop, right? I suspect I am missing something fundamental here, or otherwise why it is not that simple in TikZ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid nesting of `\tikz` commands and environments `tikzpicture`. This is not well supported.

The example is fixed by removing the unnecessary `\tikz` commands:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (c0) at (5cm,5cm);
    \draw (c0) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
    \coordinate (c1) at ($(c0)+(5cm,0cm)$);
    \draw (c1) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, the example can be simplified to, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\draw
        (5cm, 5cm) ellipse (3cm and 1cm)
        ++(5cm, 0cm) ellipse (3cm and 1cm)
    ;
\end{document}
```

or for more complex drawings:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw
            (5cm, 5cm) ellipse (3cm and 1cm)
            ++(5cm, 0cm) ellipse (3cm and 1cm)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```